# Invisible intercepting element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to browse the chefsteps account (this one worked) and click the chefsteps account in my instagram account (the clicking part does not work). But I got "Element Click Intercepted Exception". There is no visible dialog box, but the 'chefsteps' button (element click) is intercepted. What should I do to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\Day52_instagram_followers_bot\main.py", line 65, in <module>

    bot.find_followers()

  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\Day52_instagram_followers_bot\main.py", line 38, in find_followers

    chefsteps.click()

  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click

    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute

    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute

    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="_3SOD">...</div> is not clickable at point (207, 135). Other element would receive the click: <div class="jLwSh" role="dialog"></div>

  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)


import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from time import sleep
 
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH ="C:\Development\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
SIMILAR_ACCOUNT = "chefsteps"
INSTAGRAM_EMAIL = os.environ['YOUR_INSTAGRAM_EMAIL']
INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD = os.environ['YOUR_INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD']
 
class InstaFollower:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
 
    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
        sleep(3)
        email = self.driver.find_element_by_name('username')
        email.send_keys(INSTAGRAM_EMAIL)
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_name('password')
        password.send_keys(INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD)
        password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        pass
 
    def find_followers(self):
        sleep(3)
        notif = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
        notif.click()
        browser = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("x3qfX")
        browser.send_keys(SIMILAR_ACCOUNT)
        sleep(7)
        try:
            chefsteps = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('uL8Hv')
            chefsteps.click()
        except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
            chefsteps = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._4EzTm div')
            chefsteps.click()
 
 
    def follow(self):
        sleep(7)
        followers_button = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('-nal3')
        followers_button.click()
        sleep(5)
        number_of_followers = int(followers_button.get_attribute("title").replace(",", ""))
        print(number_of_followers)
        n = 1
        while n < number_of_followers:
            try:
                follow_buttons = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("y3zKF")
                for i in follow_buttons:
                    sleep(1)
                    i.click()
            except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
                cancel = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("HoLwm")
                cancel.click()
                continue
 
bot = InstaFollower()
 
bot.login()
bot.find_followers()
bot.follow()
```

Comment: Please share relevant HTML code. where is the element located (You can attach a pic of that), or else it's better to mention the steps to navigate to this button.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

1: Not sure where the button appears, If the Element appears after **Scrolling**:

```
chefsteps = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('uL8Hv')
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",chefsteps)
chefsteps.click()
```

2: Can use `ActionsChains`:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

chefsteps = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('uL8Hv')
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(chefsteps).click().perform()
```

3: Use Javascript:

```
chefsteps = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('uL8Hv')
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",chefsteps)
```

If none of the above methods work, check if the Element is in an `Iframe` or `shadow-root`. And also check for the locator you are using, It should be unique in the DOM that is 1/1.

Comment: Thank you. The ActionChains solution works well.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you can accept the answer. Click on `✓` on the left side of the answer for the same.